# Как укоротить строку и вывести только нужное

Tags: php

Помогите укоротить строку и вывести нужное мне значение. Например: В
`$question->post_date` у меня дата из 19 строк `'2016-01-05 16:30:51'` как сделать чтобы выводилось только дата!??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте функцию [substr](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php)

```
substr($question->post_date, 0, 10);
```

Берем из строки первые 10 символов

Comment: А если изменится формат даты? ;)

Comment: Ну я скорее отвечал на основной вопрос в заголовке "как укоротить строку", если изменится формат - то тут уже ничего не поможет. Можно в регулярку заложить дату \d\d-\d\d ... А ее возьмут и начнут разделять `/` или месяц буквами напишут :)

Answer (score 2):

И как вариант, если дата и время нужны отдельно:

```
$str = "2016-01-01 00:00:00";

$arr = explode($str, ' ');
```

`$arr[0]` - это будет дата.

`$arr[1]` - это будет время.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужна текущая дата, можете использовать [date()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php) ,без второго аргумента. В первом аргументе можете выбрать удобный формат вывода.
Вывод текущей даты как в примере будет выглядеть date("Y-m-d")

Answer (score 1):

```
Date("Y-m-d", strtotime($question->post_date))
```

Думаю такой вариант Вам подойдёт